# Experience Manager button not rendered properly in Chrome

Tags: experience-manager

We are converting from SiteEdit to XPM as part of an SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1 migration for CWA application.

XPM works perfectly when I create a sample test Page, but when I implement the same on existing Pages, the button is not displayed properly and shows below error in `bootstrap.aspx`.

> Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object HTMLInputElement]_lo_lblf.filter @ Bootstrap.aspx?mode=js:25f @ Bootstrap.aspx?mode=js:25document.querySelectorAll.f @ Bootstrap.aspx?mode=js:25Tridion.$$ @ Bootstrap.aspx?mode=js:25Tridion.$ @ Bootstrap.aspx?mode=js:25Tridion.Controls.LoadingOverlay.initialize @ Bootstrap.aspx?mode=js:38Tridion.ControlRegistry.createControl @ Bootstrap.aspx?mode=js:33j @ Bootstrap.aspx?mode=js:41(anonymous function) @ Bootstrap.aspx?mode=js:41(anonymous function) @ Bootstrap.aspx?mode=js:41

The button is not rendered properly and just shown as text at the bottom of the page, but when I click on it, I am able to edit that Page.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm the pages are HTML compliant, for instance by checking the source of them on https://validator.w3.org/?

Comment: Yes, i verified it. It is HTML compliant.

Comment: I still think there is something wrong with the HTML on that page, perhaps you can edit your question and add the source of the HTML page? Or try with a different Page (Page Template), with just some basic HTML, to confirm it really is related to this specific Page or not.